# How to terminate endless while loop via setTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a piece of code with while loop which I would like to stop by setTimeout(). But it seems like a endless loop, which never triggers setTimeout(). If I remove while loop, timeout triggers correctly. What is wrong please?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var i = 0, s = false;

    setTimeout( function()
    {
        s = true;
        console.log( "Timeuot!!!" );
        console.log( "s value is " + s );
    }, 1000 );

    while( s === false )
    {
        console.log( "this is while and s is " + s );
        i++;
    }

    console.log( "iterations: " + i );
});
```

Comment: @Quentin the `s` inside the setTimeout is set at the global scope. why am I wrong ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir — The function passed to `setTimeout` is defined inside another function. It has access to the scope of that function. Since there is a non-global `s` in that scope, it accesses that `s`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir h s inside the setTimeout is the one of the enclosing scope so the one declared and defined a couple of lines above.

Comment: @Quentin oh man you're right. my bad. deleting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript runs a single event loop. It won't stop in the middle of a function to see if there are any events (such as clicks or timeouts) that would trigger a different function.

In short: It won't run the timed function until the while loop has finished.

---

To do this sort of thing, you'd normally have an event driven iterator.

```js
var i = 0,
  s = false;

setTimeout(function() {
  s = true;
  console.log("Timeuot!!!");
  console.log("s value is " + s);
}, 1000);

next();

function next() {
  if (s) {
    return done();
  }
  console.log({
    s, i
  });
  i++;
  setTimeout(next, 0);
}

function done() {
  console.log("iterations: " + i);
}
```

Comment: Mmmm. But it does stop and shows that it is not infinite loop .http://jsbin.com/cewewarovo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @RoyiNamir — JSbin appears to mangle code to stop people doing DOS attacks with it. `while (s === false) {if (window.runnerWindow.protect.protect({line: 13}))break;window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log("this is while and s is " + s);i++;}` — It adds a `break` in there.

Comment: Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the while loop blocks the one and only thread. To let your example do the thing you want, replace the while loop with setInterval(function) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var i = 0, s = false;

    setTimeout( function()
    {
        s = true;
        console.log( "Timeout!!!" );
        console.log( "s value is " + s );
    }, 1000 );


    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      console.log( "this is while and s is " + s );
      i++;      
      if (s) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log("i is " + i)
      }
    }, 100);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is never called do the the fact that the while never ends and so the even dispatcher is not going to trigger the setTimeout.